# Saving form as PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form and a download button, when the form is empty I get the document as PDF, but when I fill up the form the document is not downloading. When the form is empty it's all good. Here is the PHP logic for the form,

```
     <?php 
           if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
           {
               $userName = $_POST['name'];                                       
               $email = $_POST['email'];
               $phoneNumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
               $messageSubject =$_POST['subject'];
               $message = $_POST['message'];
               $to = "rizovskinikola@gmail.com";
               $body = "";
               $body = "Hakatoni"."\r\n";
               $body .= "Ime: ".$userName. "\r\n";
               $body .= "Email: ".$email. "\r\n";
               $body .= "Telefonski broj:".$phoneNumber."\r\n"; 
               $body .= "Message: ".$message. "\r\n";
               if( mail($to,$messageSubject, $body)  ) {
                   echo "<script>
                   swal({
                     title: 'Ви благодариме за заинтересираноста!',
                     text: 'Очекувајте меил или повик од нас со повеќе информации.',
                     icon: 'success',
                     button: 'Супер!',
                   });
                            </script>";
               } else {
                 echo "<script>alert('Mail was not sent. Please try again later');</script>";
               }
           }
 ?>
```

For the JavaScript logic(to download the PDF I use this logic)

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("download")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
            const invoice = this.document.getElementById("invoice");
            console.log(invoice);
            console.log(window);
            var opt = {
                margin: 0,
                filename: 'myfile.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 1 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
            };
            html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt).save();
        })
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: Don't have any...

Comment: _"Here is the PHP logic for the form"_ - how is that relevant to the question? Your PDF generation appears to happen solely on the client side.

Comment: I think i need to make those 2 connect in some way so I can fix this problem that's why I put the PHP too

Comment: Perhaps you need to change to this `document.getElementById("download")
        .addEventListener("click", (e) => { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Why would you need to connect them? The pdf content seems to come from something already in the browser. It's completely unclear how the JS and PHP would be related to each other

Comment: Still the same @mplungjan

Comment: Because when the form is filled, it shoots out the mail and the PDF doesn't download ,so I think there's need to be some connection @ADyson

Comment: Your PHP is expecting a form and your html2pdf likely does an ajax. There is no code in the PHP that expects a file

Comment: So I suggest you use html2pdf php version instead of the js version

Comment: `Because when the form is filled, it shoots out the mail and the PDF doesn't download`...I can't see your form, but I would guess probably this is because it posts back the form, which of course destroys the current page and therefore the JS never executes. I suggest submitting the form via AJAX so you can then run other JS without the whole page resetting.